# Download file using Azure Storage with resume download

Tags: android, file, download, azure-storage, resume-download

I want to resumable a file download from the Azure server.

I've tried with many third-party libraries. i.e PRDownloader, Fetch but Azure file is restart download while network issue OR any.

Referred c# code

```
var blobRequestOptions = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions
            {
                RetryPolicy = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies.ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 3),
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                StoreBlobContentMD5 = true
            };
```

But not getting how it'll work in android. Can any one help to short it out. Help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [BlobRequestOptions](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-android/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobRequestOptions.html) class, there is a same method [`setTimeoutIntervalInMs`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-android/com/microsoft/azure/storage/RequestOptions.html#setTimeoutIntervalInMs(java.lang.Integer)) like the `ServerTimeout` property.

And about the example about setting the `BlobRequestOptions` properties, you could refer to this github code: [MaximumExecutionTimeTests.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/blob/2c643c37c6b8c9081058add284c601a2393afc93/microsoft-azure-storage-test/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/MaximumExecutionTimeTests.java#L57), it sets the MaximumExecutionTime and TimeoutInterval.

So you could combine the example with [setRetryPolicyFactory](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-android/com/microsoft/azure/storage/RequestOptions.html#setRetryPolicyFactory(com.microsoft.azure.storage.RetryPolicyFactory)) to achieve the same effect like the c# code you post.